# How to count number of cyclic permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and I want to get number of cyclic permutations like $\{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3\}$.

But the next numbers in this cycle must be not greater than three. So next to $1$ can be $2, 3$ and $4$, but not $5$ and $6$.

I know the answer for this example, but I want to know how to generalize it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you apply the "not greater than three (difference)" rule when an entry decreases in the cycle?  What if any restriction is placed on cycle length?

Comment: The length of this cyclic permutation must be 6 and I mean that the next element must not greater than three.

Comment: You've said that 6 cannot follow 1, but my question is whether 1 can follow 6?

Comment: Please clarify your Question, particularly as you ask about generalizing the problem (presumably meaning different length cycles and different "gap" sizes allowed).